# Strange white boxes in output

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, input, file-io

I need to read a text file, and then store all the characters in it into a 2D character array for a maze program. My problem is that when I try to print them out they appear as white boxes. I've attached an image for further clarification.

The txt file named data4-1.txt is as follows,

4 5
0 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 1 1 0 1
0 1 2 0 1
0 1 0 0 1

- In the image, the first block is what the output should look like, while the second block is what it appears as.

[image]

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Testing4 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char[][] maze = new char[100][100];
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\15mik_000\\Desktop\\Text\\data4-1.txt")); //reading files in specified directory
            String line;
            while ((line = in .readLine()) != null) //file reading
            {
                String[] values = line.split(" ");
                for (String str: values) {
                    char curr = str.charAt(0);
                    maze[x][y] = curr;
                    System.out.print(maze[x][y] + " ");
                    y++;
                }
                System.out.println("");
                x++;
            }

            int rows = Character.getNumericValue(maze[0][0]);
            int columns = Character.getNumericValue(maze[0][1]);
            // System.out.println(maze[1][0]+1-1); //Gives me a box 
            printArray(maze, rows, columns); in .close();
        } catch (IOException ioException) {}

    }
    public static void printArray(char[][] maze, int rows, int columns) {

        for (int i = 2; i < rows + 2; i++) {
            System.out.println("");
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                System.out.print(maze[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the contents of your file?

Comment: Sorry, I just added that in

Comment: As per the image, values of `maze[0][0]` and `maze[0][1]` are both `0` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your file contents, I would prefer a `Scanner` and `nextInt`. I would also size the `maze` based on the first two `int`(s) and I would store `int`(s). You could use a [`try-with-resources` close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and `Arrays.deepToString(Object[])` for a quick check on the `maze` contents. Something like,

```
String folder = "C:\\Users\\15mik_000\\Desktop\\Text";
String file = "data4-1.txt";
File f = new File(folder, file);
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f)) {
    int rows = scanner.nextInt();
    int cols = scanner.nextInt();
    int[][] maze = new int[rows][cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            maze[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(maze));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have got the `printArray(...)` logic wrong.

I think it should look like

```
public static void printArray(char[][] maze, int rows, int columns) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        j+=2;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            System.out.println("");
            for (int k = 0; k < columns; k++)
                System.out.print(maze[x][j++] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

By the way, **this will only work with the way you are currently populating the `maze` array**. But I see a **bug in the way you are populating the `maze` array** as you read from file.

Once you make `x++` then shouldn't you be making `y=0`. If so, accordingly you need to change the `printArray` logic.

Apart from that consider using the `Scanner` to read the file as suggested by Elliott.